# What could "I've come John Alden" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Situation is: a Brazilian woman come to a American young lady.

**B: I've come, like you say, Jack Alden.**

**A: Jack Alden? Oh, you mean John Alden?**

**B: That's the fellow. I have a message for you. An invitation from a charming young man.**

It's from a movie. There's no character called Alden in it. I feel it's some kind of idiom, but Google gives me absolutely no clue what **"I've come John Alden"** could mean.

Comment: What movie is this from?  It doesn't seem to make much sense, but it might make more sense in context.  Is it possible that the character is not speaking correctly because English is not her first language?

Comment: Nancy Goes to Rio, 1950. The Brazilian speaks very correctly during the movie. I don't see more context I can give. A man asks Brazilian to invite the American girl to have dinner with him. Then goes the dialogue. After that they're just having discussion. This "alden" completely confuses me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This refers to a poem by Longfellow, 'The Courtship of Miles Standish'. Miles Standish, an elderly soldier, asks his more articulate young friend John Alden to convey his proposal of marriage to Priscilla, not knowing that Alden is also in love with her. Alden carries out Standish's commission; but Priscilla rejects Standish's proposal and invites Alden to "Speak for yourself, John."

The Brazilian says she comes "like John Alden": to communicate an invitation from a third party.